# jQuery Filter ANCHOR tag in <td>

Tags: php, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table_class table td").hover(function() {
        $(".table_class table td a").filter(function() {
         showinTitle($(this));
        });
    });
});

function showinTitle($Object){
    $Object.prop('title', $Object.html());
}
```

What i need means,  For Long text i have given overflow hidden and text overflow-ellipsis,

when i hover means all `<td>` values need to display in title when its hover, except the `<a>`tag

Answer (score 0):

```
function showinTitle($Object){
    var title = $Object.html();
    var wrapped = $("<div>" + title + "</div>");
    wrapped.find("a").remove();
    $Object.prop('title', wrapped.html());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function is for removing elements from a set based on a condition, so you shouldn't be using it for this problem.

If the content of your `td` elements is simply text with some anchor tags, and you want to display the title `"title with link"` for a td like `<td>title with <a>link</a></td>`, then you can just use the text of the td to generate the title:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".table_class table td").each(function() {
    $(this).prop('title', $(this).text())
  })
})
```

If you're trying to make the title for each td show everything except the contents of anchor tags (that is, if you want to show the title `"title with"` for a td like `<td>title with <a>link</a></td>`), then you'll need to do something similar to what Arvind suggests:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".table_class table td").each(function() {
    var contents = $("<td>" + $(this).html() + "</td>");
    contents.find("a").remove();
    $(this).prop('title', contents.text())
  })
})
```

This loops through each td when the document loads, and creates a temporary clone of it. The anchor tags are then removed from the clone, and the title of the td is set to the (cleaned) contents of the clone.